# Hibernate genericDao projection

Tags: hibernate, genericdao

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.7.Final with [Google genericDAO](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) 1.2.0. I'm interested in how can I write a search with group by?

For example:

```
select a, sum(b) from table group by a
```

with

```
Search search = new Search();
search.addFieldGroupBy("a"); //this does not exist, I need something like this
search.addField("b", Field.OP_SUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate group by query is same as your native SQL other then you will have here your Persistent Object name.

```
select a, sum(b) from table t group by t.a
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question, coz I know that this is the query but now I need a Search object for groupping by a field.